# Why does "extern int &c;" working fine?

Tags: c++, variables, reference, extern

In C++, reference variable must be initialized.
    int &a; // Error

```
static int &b; // Error
```

But

```
extern int &c; // No error
```

Why Compiler doesn't give an error for `extern` specifier reference?

Comment: Because the initialization is forced to happen in the external definition.

Comment: The `extern`  bit tells the compiler that `c` is declared/defined somewhere else

Comment: @rsp  extern int &c; is not a definition of a reference. It is just a declaration without the definition.

Comment: `extern int &peach; string toad = "but our princess is in another castle";`

Comment: Consider what would have to happen if it were possible.  Now the linker has to figure out what to do when the extern declaration and the actual declaration don't have the same initializer.  Linkers are not that smart.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `extern` keyword is a directive for the compiler that you are now declaring a symbol that will be filled in during linking, taken from another object file.
The initialization is EXPECTED to happen where the actual symbol is defined.

If you have an a.c file with

```
int foo;
int &bar = foo;
```

And a b.c file with

```
extern int &bar;
```

When you compile the file b.c into b.o the compiler will leave the symbol for `bar` empty. When linking the program, the linker will need to find the exported symbol `bar` in a.o and will then replace the blank symbol in b.o with the `bar` from a.o

If the linker can't find the required symbol anywhere in the linked object files - a Linker error (not compiler error) will be issued.

Answer (score 5):

> Why Compiler doesn't give an error for `extern` reference?

Because `extern int &c;` is not a definition, but merely a **declaration**. It's informing the compiler that `c` will be defined somewhere else in the program.

The [cppreference page on "storage class specifiers"](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration) explains the meaning of `extern` in this scenario.

Answer (score 5):

The language specification explicitly says

> **8.3.2 References**
>   **5** [...] The declaration of a reference shall contain an initializer (8.6.3) except when the declaration contains an explicit `extern` specifier (7.1.1), is a class member (9.2) declaration within a class definition, or is the declaration of
>   a parameter or a return type (8.3.5); see 3.1.

Your situation is directly covered by this quote. In other words, references are not excepted from the general declaration-definition rule. You can create a non-defining declaration for a reference defined (and initialized) elsewhere.

Nobody prohibits you from including an initializer into a reference declaration with an explicit `extern` keyword. However, as usual, it will turn a non-defining declaration into a *definition*.